# mongodb schema design embedded or reference

Tags: mongodb, reference, schema

I am new to mongodb and I want to create the following simple schema.

I will describe it in relational thinking:
3 tables -> company , product , deals

company is related one to many to deals.
product is related one to many to deals.

So the deals table is the link between company and product 
It would have the following structure

deal_id | company_id | product_id | extra_fields

how should I implement this structure to mongodb ? Should I use embedded modeling or references?
What do you suggest??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends...See here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/

Comment: I agree with @heinob, this all depends on what data you have and how you are going to use it. There is not a definitive answer at this point to say do it one way or another. Unless you want to get **specific** about what you **want** to do, anything else is just speculation.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would do exactly the same as you would in in your flat, non hierachal or structured SQL relational database, using 3 tables.

You could say that deals would be embedded into company and maybe they could be but if deals were changing often you could see fragmentation within the top level document due to non in-place updates.

An in-place update is specified by one which does not require the document to move to another part of the disk in order to be able to be stored. This is of course a lot faster and less over head than one which requires to be moved to a new contigeous part of the disk. Not only that but the left over space, if your unlucky, could be left there without ever being filled.

The only way to fix such a situation is to run a `db.repair()` regularly which some users do for some reason.

Instead with that in mind and the usage and query patterns of deals I would think they should go into their own table.